# How to grab some character after "-"?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

Suppose I have an "option code" column in my tbl, the data is like this:

```
m1803-C-2550
m1807-P-3050
```

I want to grab C/P between "-" as my new variable "option type", and 2550/3050 after the second "-" as my new variable "strike price".

How do I code with `tidyverse`?

Now, I could solve the first question by

```
tbl %>% mutate(option_type = str_sub(option_code, str_locate(option_code, "[CP]"))
```

But I could not solve my second question, or you guys may have an elegant way to solve my first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

  df %>% 
  mutate(option_type = str_extract(option_code, "(?<=-)[CP]"),
         strike_price = as.numeric(str_extract(option_code, "(?<=-)\\d+")))

#>    option_code option_type strike_price
#> 1 m1803-C-2550           C         2550
#> 2 m1807-P-3050           P         3050
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(option_code =  c("m1803-C-2550", "m1807-P-3050"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The alternative marker `|` is not needed in the character class; there, any characters can occur in any order and any combination.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate()` in `tidyr` to split strings by a separator.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(option_code, c(NA, "option_type", "strike_price"))

#   option_type strike_price
# 1           C         2550
# 2           P         3050
```

- `NA` means to drop the first part, i.e. `m1803`.
- If you want to keep `option_code`, then just add the argument `remove = F`.

---

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(option_code = c("m1803-C-2550", "m1807-P-3050"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract`from `stringr`:

```
df %>% mutate(option_type = str_extract(option_code, "[CP]"),
              strike_price = str_extract(option_code, "(?<=[CP]-)\\d+"))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  option_code  option_type strike_price
  <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       
1 m1803-C-2550 C           2550        
2 m1807-P-3050 P           3050
```

Data:

```
df <- tibble(option_code = c("m1803-C-2550","m1807-P-3050"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Sometimes, option_code would start with C or P， so I think @Peter 's answer is better.

Comment: As noted above, the syntax of character classes such as `[CP]`allows for the characters included in them to occur in any order and any combination. So `[CP]` matches: `C`, `P`, `CP`, `PC`

Comment: What I mean is the first option_type, the first several codes actually are the commodity    code, in this example, it is "m", but maybe the code would be P or C next time.  If use [CP], maybe there would be some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
setNames(data.frame(lapply(strsplit(tmp, "-"),"[", -1)), c("option_type", "strike_price"))
```

Data:

```
tmp <- c("m1803-C-2550",
         "m1807-P-3050")
```